# VS Code's Jade syntax highlighting is bad

Tags: pug, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code

**Why does my Jade syntax highlighting look bad in VS Code?** *(e.g. commented meta when I add line before, last comment always)*

**Did I mess up the syntax or it's simply VS Code's fault?**

It's not the first time and it starts to really annoy me, but I'd rather solve it because I really like VS Code

Here's my code:

```
    doctype html
    html
        head
            title= title
            meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-    scale=1')

            // - meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width,     initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no')

            // - Files that need to be included at top
            include ./partials/_include_at_top.jade
            block extra-styles
        body
            include ./partials/_main-nav.jade
            .page
                block content

            // - Files that need to be included at bottom
            include ./partials/_include_at_bottom.jade
```

[image]

[image]

[Images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1cZZXb4N-rmcDNaYnRhRDAwcDQ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax highlighting is bad with the comments due to [this issue with the language grammar in VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3202).

`include`, `block`, etc. not being highlighting is due to the fact you're using the older "Dark (Visual Studio)" theme. We recommend you change to the "Dark+ theme" by doing the following:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
- Type `theme`
- Select Dark+ (or another theme) from the list

---

You also appear to be wanting to use the [don't render comment to HTML feature](http://jade-lang.com/reference/comments/), this is done by using `//-`, not `// -`.

Comment: **Cool. Thanks a lot!** I don't have pesmission to mark the answer as useful, but someone should definitely do.

Answer (score 1):

If you drop your code at [jade-lang.com](http://jade-lang.com/) you'll see that it states

```
Jade:10
    8| 
    9|         // - Files that need to be included at top
  > 10|         include ./partials/_include_at_top.jade
    11|         block extra-styles
    12|     body
    13|         include ./partials/_main-nav.jade

the "filename" option is required to use "include" with "relative" paths
```

wich is a little bit missleading as it should better state that the issues is that your to-be-included jade files could not be found. If I produce the "missing" jade files the template is rendered with the node module without errors.

So either there are files missing or it's an displaying issue within vs code.

Comment: Yeah I got the file paths correct as they add the estimated extra content to the layout. I'm checking the "filename option" as I set up Express for the first time and I don't see where it sets the option in app.js. I'll be back as I find something.

Comment: However since things are loaded correctly, maybe VS Code has just a minor syntax problem.